# Swift compiler error: Bitcast requires both operands to be pointer or neither

Tags: ios, swift, nscoding

I am getting the above compiler error on the following class:

```
class Log: NSObject, NSCoding {

var targetHoursPerWeek: Double
var weeksLog: Double[]

// Serialization keys that are using to implement NSCoding.
struct SerializationKey {
    static let targetHoursPerWeek = "targetHoursPerWeek"
    static let weeksLog = "weeksLog"
}

init() {

    targetHoursPerWeek = 7.0
    weeksLog = Double[](count: 7, repeatedValue: 0.0)
    // [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

}

// MARK: NSCoding

init(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
    targetHoursPerWeek = decoder.decodeObjectForKey(SerializationKey.targetHoursPerWeek) as Double
     weeksLog = decoder.decodeObjectForKey(SerializationKey.weeksLog) as Double[]
}

func encodeWithCoder(encoder: NSCoder) {
    encoder.encodeObject(targetHoursPerWeek, forKey: SerializationKey.targetHoursPerWeek)
    encoder.encodeObject(weeksLog, forKey: SerializationKey.weeksLog)
}
```

}

I believe that the error comes from the line

```
 weeksLog = decoder.decodeObjectForKey(SerializationKey.weeksLog) as Double[]
```

but if so I am stumped -- the "as Double[]" agrees with the declaration of "weeksLog".
So I am stumped!

Comment: I reproduced this and read the complete compiler error message.  Something is going wrong there at a lower level. So this is a bug for sure. You should report it.

Comment: But you are wrong: The compiler runs fine if you remove this line: encoder.encodeObject(weeksLog, forKey: SerializationKey.weeksLog). Maybe you can write a workaround that does not cause the compiler to make trouble.

Comment: I will give the workaround a try.  Do you have suggestions?

Comment: Thanks for pinpointing the error location.  That gives me something to work with.

Comment: This now works:

    encoder.encodeObject(weeksLog as AnyObject[], forKey: SerializationKey.weeksLog)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

I changed weeksLog to be an optional and changed as to as? and it compiles.

```
var weeksLog: Double[]?
```

and

```
weeksLog = decoder.decodeObjectForKey(SerializationKey.weeksLog) as? Double[]
```